# Generate multiple nodes with same name in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using XSLT

Input is like below

```
<data>
    <details>
        <DATA>
            <name>nameValue</name>
        </DATA>
        <DATA>
            <name>nameValue1</name>
        </DATA>
    <details>
<data>
```

XSLT is

```
<xsl:template match="details">
    <xsl:copy>
        <info>
            <person_name>
                <xsl:value-of select="DATA/name"/>
            </person_name>
        </info>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

output

```
<info>
    <person_name>nameValue</person_name>
</info>
```

Expected output is like below

```
<info>
    <person_name>nameValue</person_name>
</info>
<info>
    <person_name>nameValue1</person_name>
</info>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML is not well-formed, as it has opening tag where closing tags should be. But assuming it looked like this...

```
<data>
    <details>
        <DATA>
            <name>nameValue</name>
        </DATA>
        <DATA>
            <name>nameValue1</name>
        </DATA>
    </details>
</data>
```

... what you need to do is use an `xsl:for-each` to select each child `DATA` element

```
<xsl:template match="details">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="DATA">
            <info>
                <person_name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                </person_name>
            </info>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I update question its like data is root element then details and then DATA

Comment: By using this XSLT I am getting blank details node. I used xsl:for-each select="details"

Comment: I've amended my answer to handle your new XML structure.